# Sharedpreferences for ListViews Items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclick, sharedpreferences

...When clicking on an item in a listView (Items added by user Input) I want it to open an activity which is going to contain another ListView (which is going to be  special for that one item which we clicked on)...and let it be there forever until you delete it.

I'm basically trying to make an app where you first add lets say Car names → when you click on the name an activity opens where youll be able to add car model names to the listView → after clicking on the model name theres going to be another activity which is going to contain photos of the chosen model (photos - which you'll add there from your gallery and they will be stored there)

I hope you get what I want to do...now the question, how do you do it ? I can't seem to find any "how tos" like this and I'm really tired of trying to make it work (spent ages on this). Any tutorials or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show some code. What have you done till now?

Answer (score 0):

I think as you told you need to maintain the id of particular item of listview clicked and then show data to next activity accordingly.

For that: try to use the position of item clicked and then use the position as index to array of which have your details to show in next screen.

get position(id) of item clicked as:

```
contests_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

Toast.makeText(this,"You selected : " + item,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
Log.e("position of item",String.valueOf(position));
/*here start activity and fetch the details according to index of id for that array which will be identified by the position of item clicked.*/

            }
        });
```